# Pandas datetime: can't convert object in dd-mm-YYYY format to datetime in correct format

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a pandas dataframe

```
Sl.No   Date1
1   08-09-1990
2   01-06-1988
3   04-10-1989
4   15-11-1991
5   01-06-1968
```

The dtype of Date1 is object

When i tried  to convert this object to datetime format.

```
df["Date1"]= pd.to_datetime(df["Date1"])
```

I am getting the output as

```
0   1990-08-09
1   1988-01-06
2   1989-04-10
3   1991-11-15
4   2068-01-06
```

Also I tried with:

```
df["Date1"]= pd.to_datetime(df["Date1"],format='%d-%m-%Y')
```

and

```
df["Date1"]= pd.to_datetime(df["Date1"],format='%d-%m-%Y', dayfirst = True)
```

Problem is :

1. in index 0 the month and day is interchanged
2. in index 4 the year is taken incorrectly as 2068 instead of 1968

Comment: your bug is not reproducible. I tested your input using `dayfirst=True` and it gives me a perfectly correct output.

Comment: Thanks @RamyMohamed, You where correct it worked fine in another system

Answer (score 1):

Pass the `dayfirst` to `to_datetime`

```
pd.to_datetime(df.Date1,dayfirst=True)
0   1990-09-08
1   1988-06-01
2   1989-10-04
3   1991-11-15
4   1968-06-01
Name: Date1, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```